# Question on the upper limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis, fixed-points

Let $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function verfying the following:

1) $f$ is stricly increasing.

2) For each positive sequence $(a_n)$, we have

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a_n}=0$   iff  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{f(a_n)}=-\infty$.

3) There exists $\theta\in (0,1)$ such that $\lim_{a\rightarrow 0^+}a^\theta f(a) =0 $

Let $\tau>0$, $\{x_n\}\subset (0,\infty)$ and  $\{y_n\}\subset (0,\infty)$
such that $\{x_n\} ,\{y_n\}$ converge to $x,y>0$  and $f(x_n)\leq f(y_n)-\tau$. By using the upper limit, i want to show  that $f(x)\leq f(y)-\tau.$
Thank you.

Comment: What $\theta$ ?

Comment: Please, see (41) page 4. [hindawi.com/journals/jfs/2019/5980312] .  I need your suggegstions Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct.

Let $f$ be function satisfying condition 1,2,3 on interval $(0 , 1] $, It is easy to construct one. Now define $f$ in such way be a line with positive slope on $[1,2].$ Now continue define $f$ strictly increasing on $(2 , \infty )$ such that $f(z) \geq f(2) + 1 $, for all $z \in (2 , \infty )$. Then you have a jump at $2$.

Now by setting $x=y=2$ you have $f(x) = f(y) = f(2)$. Then easily make those sequences.

Comment: Please, see (41) page 4. https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jfs/2019/5980312/

Comment: @YoussefKarim Your claim is trivial for continuous functions

Comment: i see,  but the function not assumed continuous.